# Is this statement about quaternion function true?

Tags: analysis, operator-theory, quaternions, clifford-algebras

Let $\mathbb{H}=\{q=t+xi+yj+zk:t,x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}\}$ be the quaternions and $f:\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{H}$ be a function satisfying
$\overline{\partial_c}f=0,$
where
$$\overline{\partial_c}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\frac{\operatorname{Im}q}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right), \ \operatorname{Im}q=xi+yj+zk, \ r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2.$$
Then we have $\overline{\partial_l}\Delta f=0$, where
$$\overline{\partial_l}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+j\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+k\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right), \ \Delta=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}.$$
Is this statement true?
This statement appears in paper[1] as theorem 3.2. It also appears in the introduction of  a paper[2]. But the proof was omitted.

[1]Stover, Christopher. “A Survey of Quaternionic Analysis.” (2014).

[2]Gentili, Graziano and Daniele C. Struppa. “A New Theory of Regular Functions of a Quaternionic Variable.” Advances in Mathematics 216 (2007): 279-301.

Comment: This looks like an interesting question, but without adding context (like where the statement comes from, why you suspect it might be true, what ideas you have or work you've done), it does not meet community standards and so will be downvoted and/or closed. Please improve your question by adding context.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the source of the question. Now, I've added the source of the problem.

Comment: Looks like using the chain rule we have $\bar{\partial_c}=\bar{\partial_l}$, so that if we can commute the Laplacian $\bar{\partial_l} \Delta f = \Delta \bar{\partial_l} f = \Delta \bar{\partial_c} f=\Delta 0=0$

Comment: Yes, the chain rule is a good idea. If let $x=r\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta},y=r\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta},z=r\cos{\phi}$, I obtain $\overline{\partial_c}=\frac{1}{2}[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\frac{Imq}{r}(\frac{x}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{y}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\frac{z}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial z})]$. Besides, let $\partial_l=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\overline{\partial_l}$, we can get $\Delta=4\partial_l\overline{\partial_l}$. But my problem is still unresolved.